# System.Net.Uri with urlencoded characters

Tags: c#, .net

I need to request the following URL inside my application:

```
http://feedbooks.com/type/Crime%2FMystery/books/top
```

When I run the following code:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://feedbooks.com/type/Crime%2FMystery/books/top");
```

The `Uri` constructor decodes the `%2F` into a literal `/`, and I get a 404 error because it has changed the URL to:

```
http://feedbooks.com/type/Crime/Mystery/books/top
```

The `Uri` class has a constructor that takes a parameter `dontEscape`, but that constructor is deprecated and setting it to `true` has no effect.

My first thought was to do something like:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://feedbooks.com/type/Crime%252FMystery/books/top");
```

With the hopes that it would convert `%25` into a literal `%`, but that didn't work either.

Any ideas how to create a correct `Uri` object for this particular URL in .NET?

Comment: um... did you try \% (or \\%)... :(

Comment: I love the question.  Now, please give a Java answer for java.io.URI which has the same damn problem, but without the flags (near as I can tell)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same problem using 2.0...

I discovered a workaround posted at [this blog](http://grootveld.com/archives/21/url-encoded-slashes-in-systemuri):

```
// System.UriSyntaxFlags is internal, so let's duplicate the flag privately
private const int UnEscapeDotsAndSlashes = 0x2000000;

public static void LeaveDotsAndSlashesEscaped(Uri uri)
{
    if (uri == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("uri");
    }

    FieldInfo fieldInfo = uri.GetType().GetField("m_Syntax", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (fieldInfo == null)
    {
        throw new MissingFieldException("'m_Syntax' field not found");
    }
    object uriParser = fieldInfo.GetValue(uri);

    fieldInfo = typeof(UriParser).GetField("m_Flags", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (fieldInfo == null)
    {
        throw new MissingFieldException("'m_Flags' field not found");
    }
    object uriSyntaxFlags = fieldInfo.GetValue(uriParser);

    // Clear the flag that we don't want
    uriSyntaxFlags = (int)uriSyntaxFlags & ~UnEscapeDotsAndSlashes;

    fieldInfo.SetValue(uriParser, uriSyntaxFlags);
}
```

It works perfectly.

Hope this helps (better late than never!)

Comment: Awesome!  Stackoverflow never ceases to amaze me.

Answer (score 8):

It's a bit easier in .NET 4.0. You can put a setting in your config file like this:

```
<uri> 
<schemeSettings>
    <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes" />
</schemeSettings>
</uri>
```

It only works for the 'http' and 'https' schemes.

Or here's a new version of the LeaveDotsAndSlashesEscaped method. It doesn't need a particular Uri instance, just call it when your application starts up:

```
private void LeaveDotsAndSlashesEscaped()
{
    var getSyntaxMethod = 
        typeof (UriParser).GetMethod("GetSyntax", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (getSyntaxMethod == null)
    {
        throw new MissingMethodException("UriParser", "GetSyntax");
    }

    var uriParser = getSyntaxMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { "http" });

    var setUpdatableFlagsMethod = 
        uriParser.GetType().GetMethod("SetUpdatableFlags", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (setUpdatableFlagsMethod == null)
    {
        throw new MissingMethodException("UriParser", "SetUpdatableFlags");
    }

    setUpdatableFlagsMethod.Invoke(uriParser, new object[] {0});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/472836/uri-incorrectly-unescapes-5c-character) I filed a while back. It's supposed to be fixed in 4.0, but I'm not holding my breath.  Apparently it's still a problem in the RC.

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't found any workaround for this yet.  It's a bad one.  Go vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

By combining the 2 previous answers you can have a method you only need to call once per process that works both on .net 4 and .net 3.5.

```
// System.UriSyntaxFlags is internal, so let's duplicate the flag privately
private const int UnEscapeDotsAndSlashes = 0x2000000;

private void LeaveDotsAndSlashesEscaped()
{
    var getSyntaxMethod = 
        typeof (UriParser).GetMethod("GetSyntax", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (getSyntaxMethod == null)
    {
        throw new MissingMethodException("UriParser", "GetSyntax");
    }

    var uriParser = getSyntaxMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { "http" });

    FieldInfo flagsFieldInfo = typeof(UriParser).GetField("m_Flags", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.Instance);

    if (flagsFieldInfo == null)
    {
        throw new MissingFieldException("UriParser", "m_Flags");
    }
    int flags = (int) flagsFieldInfo.GetValue(uriParser);
    // unset UnEscapeDotsAndSlashes flag and leave the others untouched
    flags = flags & ~UnEscapeDotsAndSlashes;
    flagsFieldInfo.SetValue(uriParser, flags);

}
```