# Different behavior in Uri constructor (new Uri(Uri, String)) in two different projects

Tags: c#, .net

I have two different projects which both use a common piece of code. One is an Azure Cloud Service web site and the other is a Windows Service. The function they both call is

```
private static Uri ConstructUriFromUriAndString(
        Uri endpoint,
        string path)
    {
        // This is where we encode the url path to be valid
        string encodedPath = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(path);
        return new Uri(endpoint, encodedPath);
    }
```

When I call this function from the windows service with a uri and the encoded string "images%2fblabla.html" then the AbsoluteUri property of the Uri is "uri/images/blabla.html", which I believe is the expected behavior.

When I call this function from the Azure site with the same Uri and the same encoded string the AbsoluteUri property is "uri/images&2fblabla.html", which my later http request is choking on.

I've used "Go To Definition" in both cases and the both resolve to System.dll version 2.0.0.0. The windows service uses .NET 4 and the Azure site uses .NET 4.5. I don't think this is an issue since they both use the same System.dll assembly.

How is it possible to call the same function with the same parameters and get back different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently a known issue, and is caused by the .NET 4-4.5 discrepancy.

See also -

[System.Net.Uri with urlencoded characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320533/system-net-uri-with-urlencoded-characters)

[Accessing private members from powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709369/accessing-private-members-from-powershell/18511985#18511985)